# Mount WebDAV share on Salix

Tags: linux, mount, slackware, gvfs

I'm trying to mount a WebDAV share on [Salix OS](http://www.salixos.org/wiki/index.php/Home), a Slackware based distro.

Initially I only got the `davs://something.com:port address`; after Googling I found that I needed to use `gvfs-mount`, but when I tried it says:

> Error mounting location: Not a WebDAV enabled share

I've tried to search for the meaning or a gvfs tutorial without luck.

Given that I know the address of the WebDAV share, how do I mount it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you receive this error message but you can try `davfs2` or `fusedav` to mount the WebDAV share. The latter requires *FUSE*.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try both, I think I already have FUSE installed, just not sure how to use it.

Comment: It gets used automatically by the programs. Just make sure your user is in the `fuse` group or whatever group is set on `/dev/fuse`.